# JavaFx bind Integer to Text

Tags: text, javafx, binding, integer, label

I want text containing integer "expense" will be changed, when "expense" changes itself. But when "expense" variable changes the text continues to display 0. As far as I know it must be solved by binding? How?

```
    int expense=0;
    Text expenseAmmount = new Text(String.valueOf(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(expense)) + " $");

    TextFlow moneyStatus = new TextFlow();
    TextFlow incomeStatus = new TextFlow();
    TextFlow expenseStatus = new TextFlow();

    incomeStatus.getChildren().addAll(incomeLabel,incomeAmmount);
    expenseStatus.getChildren().addAll(expenseLabel,expenseAmmount);
    moneyStatus.getChildren().addAll(moneyLabel,moneyAmmount);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found it by myself :

```
    IntegerProperty property = new SimpleIntegerProperty(expense);
    expenseAmmount.textProperty().bind(property.asString());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IntegerProperty property = new SimpleIntegerProperty(expense);
expenseAmmount.textProperty().bind(property, new NumberStringConverter());
```

`expenseAmmount.textProperty().bind(property.asString());` was not working for me